API Request is delayed and not hitting the server
i have been trying this api for hours and its not working for some reason.
I have created a course route and reviewed it multiple times but still its not working.
anyone who can help me out. I will be thankful for it. I am attaching the code snippets for course model, course controller, course service and course route.
//course route
import express from "express";
import { uploadCourse } from "../controllers/course.controller";
import { authorizeRoles, isAuthenticated } from "../middleware/auth";
const courseRouter = express.Router();

courseRouter.post("/create-course",isAuthenticated, authorizeRoles("admin"),uploadCourse);



export default courseRouter;

//course service
import {Response} from "express";
import  CourseModel  from "../models/course.model";

//create course
export const createCourse = async (data:any, res:Response) => {
    const course = await CourseModel.create(data);
    res.status(201).json({
        success: true,
        course,
        message: "Course created successfully",
    });
};

//course controller
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import ErrorHandler from "../utilis/errorhandler";
import { createCourse } from "../services/course.service";
import cloudinary from "cloudinary";


//upload course
export const uploadCourse = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try{
        const data= req.body;
        const thumbnail=data.thumbnail;
        if(thumbnail){
            const myCloud=await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(thumbnail,{
                folder:"courses"
            });
            data.thumbnail={
                public_id:myCloud.public_id,
                url:myCloud.secure_url
            }
        }
        
   createCourse(data,res);

    }
    catch(error:any){
        next(new ErrorHandler(500, error.message));
    }

};

//course mdel
import mongoose, {Document, Model, Schema} from "mongoose";


interface IComment extends Document {
    user: object;
    comment: string;
    commentReplies?: IComment[];  
}
interface IReview extends Document {
    user: object;
    rating: number;
    comment: string;
    commentReplies: IComment[];
}

interface ILink extends Document {
    title: string;
    url: string;
}

interface ICourseData extends Document {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    videoUrl: string;
    videoSection: string;
    videoLength: number;
    videoPlayer: string;
    links: ILink[];
    suggestion: string;
    questions: IComment[];
}

interface ICourse extends Document {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    price: number;
    estimatedPrice?: number;
    discount: number;
    thumbnail: object;
    tags:string;
    level: string;
    demoUrl: string;
    benefits:{title:string}[];
    prerequisites:{title:string}[];
    reviews: IReview[];
    courseData: ICourseData[];
    ratings?: number;
    purchased?: number;
}

const reviewSchema = new Schema<IReview>({
    user:Object,
    rating:{
        type:Number,
        default:0,
    },
    comment:String,
});

const linkSchema= new Schema<ILink> ({
    title: String,
    url: String,
});

const commetSchema =new Schema<IComment>({
    user: Object,
    comment: String,
    commentReplies: [Object],
});

const courseDataSchema = new Schema<ICourseData>({
    videoUrl: String,
    title: String,
    description: String,
    videoSection: String,
    videoLength: Number,
    videoPlayer: String,
    links: [linkSchema],
    suggestion: String,
    questions: [commetSchema],
});

const courseSchema = new Schema<ICourse>({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    description:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        
        
    },
    price:{
        type:Number,
        required:true,
    },
    estimatedPrice:{
        type:Number,
    },
    thumbnail:{
        public_id:{
            type:String,
        },
        url:{
            type:String,
        },

    },
    tags:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    level:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    demoUrl:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    benefits:[{
        title: String,
    }],
    prerequisites:[{
        title: String,
    }],
    reviews:[reviewSchema],
    courseData:[courseDataSchema],
    ratings:{
        type:Number,
        default:0,
    },
    purchased:{
        type:Number,
        default:0,
    },

});

const CourseModel:Model<ICourse> = mongoose.model("Course",courseSchema);
export default CourseModel;

I searcheed for problems and different solutions but didnt find any related to this and also my code seems correct.

I don't see any code actually doing a request to that backend. You receive any errors at the client side? "delayed and not hitting the server" sounds like you are requesting the wrong ip/port

Try adding a console.log in uploadCourse to check if the request reaches, if it does, then check the ErrorHandler whether you are sending the response in case of error; if not, then check the middlewares, maybe you forgot to call next in any of them?

i am using postman to create the request to server its returning all other api endpoints and errors smoothly i gues thers some problem in this route or code i reviewed error handlers and middlewares they are working fine

thanks @VinayakVohra for the help i debugged and found that i was not calling next(); in authorizeRoles middleware so it was not working.
